# How to find the last date in the longest consecutive streak of dates in a column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73302673/return-longest-streak-of-consecutive-dates-in-a-google-sheets-column/73311505#73311505) which was answered by Player0, how would we write a formula to find the last date in the longest consecutive streak, which would be July 12?

[image: July 12 would be the right answer]

And similarly, is there a way to find the last date of the latest streak, which would be July 23?

[image: July 23 would be the right answer]

I’ve tried various ways of using INDEX and MATCH, along with other functions, and nothing’s been working so far.

Comment: Excel and Google sheets differ, you can't tag both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach:*

```js
=let(Σ,A5:A,
     Λ,scan(,Σ,lambda(a,c,ifs(c="",,row(c)=row(Σ),1,c-1=offset(c,-1,),a+1,1,1))),
     filter(Σ,Λ=max(Λ)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For MAX streak date, try-

```
=LET(x,QUERY(VSTACK(0,SCAN(0,INDEX(A6:A24-A5:A23),LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x=1,a+1,1)))),"limit " & COUNTA(A5:A)),
INDEX(A5:A,MATCH(MAX(x),x,0)))
```

[image]