# Count Number of Non Consecutive Occurrence of values in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, job-scheduling

I use Google Sheets to manage the schedule of 17 rotating shift workers. The draft schedule runs out 9 months. It's easy for myself to loose track of folks working too many days in a row covering shifts with overtime due to workload demands and others taking leave. I'm looking to the count max number of days a person would work in a row as I wish to limit and avoid staff burnout. My initial thinking would be to count the number of consecutive days which are **NOT** a dash ("-") as a dash indicates a scheduled day off. It would also be wonderful to indicated corresponding dates of non-consecutive days (i.e. 15 dates between X and X).

[image: sample rotating schedule]

This comes close to what I envision, but haven't played with it. [Return longest streak of consecutive dates in a Google Sheets column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73302673/return-longest-streak-of-consecutive-dates-in-a-google-sheets-column)

Comment: What does "to indicated corresponding dates of non-consecutive days (i.e. 15 dates between X and X)" mean? I think it would be helpful if you specify what defines the first date and what defines a last date (your X and X).

Comment: Would you please provide sample data (not an image) AND an example of the report that you expect to generate. Would you also confirm that each column relate to a specific employee

Comment: Argyll, so if there are 15 counts between dashes, it return the first non dash date and last non dash date.  Something like:

15 straight workdays between 2/1/24 and 2/15/24

Comment: Tedinoz, here is a sample schedule sheet.  The letters represents various shift start times while the dashes " - " indicate a day off. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15tC9c-7AWvX-K6u8xe_IUcu8XmDhZI7Z9E2wKVDt7tU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you ***manually*** calculate and showcase the ideal output you are expecting to see for couple of scenarios maybe?!

Comment: rockinfreakshow, i don't know if it was you that helped get the consecutive count, but can we get the dates to show as well?

Comment: dates added as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=max(scan(,filter(D$2:O,D$1:O$1=U5),lambda(a,c,if(or(c="-",c="",c="AL"),,a+1))))
```

[image]

***for consecutive days***:

```js
=let(Σ,scan(,filter(D$2:O,D$1:O$1=U5),lambda(a,c,if(or(c="-",c="",c="AL"),,a+1))),
     Λ,+filter(B$2:B,Σ=max(Σ)),
     to_text(Λ-max(Σ)+1)&" - "&to_text(Λ))
```

Comment: rockinfreakshow, that does the count beautifully. learned a new function that i will employee in other sheets.

The other wish is to have it display the date range of that consecutive count.

Comment: happy camper. thanks, rockinfreakshow for the brain power.